# Responsive hover text over 3 inline boxes

Tags: html, css

I have three in line boxes of which I am trying to achieve responsive text on hover to no avail. Here's my code for one of the three boxes, and here's the responsive result: http://screencast.com/t/87vPEWeJln

```css
ul.serv-img li {
   display: block;
   height: 303px;
   margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  position: relative;
   width: 347px;
 max-width: 100%;
}

span.serv-text {
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   color: white;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: table;
   height: 303px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
    left: 0;
   width: 347px;
 opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
   -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
   -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
   transition: opacity 500ms;
}

span.serv-text span {
   display: table-cell;
 padding-top: 20px;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: top;
}


ul.serv-img li:hover span.serv-text {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h4>Bookkeeping</h4>
    <ul class="serv-img">
        <li>
            <img src="http://newsite.peakcitybookkeeping.com/wp-    content/uploads/2015/11/Bookkeeping-Services.jpg" width="347" height="303">
            <span class="serv-text">
                <span>
                    Accounts Payable
                    Accounts Receivable
                    Bank & Credit Car Reconciliations
                    Monthly Financial Reports
                    Sales & Use Tax Reports
                    Payroll & Payroll Tax Filing
                    W2s & 1099s
                    Job Coaching & Profitability Analysis
                </span>
            </span>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you try to be more clear about what you're trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: What is *"responsive text on hover"*?

Comment: BTW...each one of those lines of text should probably be in it's own span...just saying.

Comment: Image is responsive, but the text does not adjust and flows outside the box. Here's a snapshot. http://screencast.com/t/87vPEWeJln

Answer (score 0):

try to use `overflow:hidden`
also in order to truncate long texts you could try:

```
 white-space: nowrap
  overflow: hidden
  text-overflow: ellipsis // This is where the magic happens
```

Comment: Thanks, lonut Milas, but that did not work. Is there better way to this up?

Comment: I could help, but please create a jsfiddle with your code so that we can test it.